# Awk in eval - shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, redirect, awk, eval

I need to construct the command with awk and run using eval command. I could not get the approach and quoting the commands. Goal is to find the ports running and redirect the output with date to file.

```
#!/bin/bash
curuser=$USER
curworkdir=`pwd`
log_dir="/tmp/logs"
ports_log_file="${log_dir}/netstat_output.log"
ports_not_listening="/tmp/logs/ports_not_listening.out"
echo $log_dir
echo $ports_log_file
if [[ ! -e $ports_log_dir ]]; then
    mkdir -p "$ports_log_dir"
fi
eval "netstat -na | grep [0-9]:80|awk -vabc=$ports_log_file 'BEGIN{"date"|getline d;}/80/{print d,\$0 >> abc  }'"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "error port 80" >> $ports_not_listening
else
        echo "Print success for port-80: $?"    # expected result is 0 exit status
fi
cmd-out=$(netstat -na | grep [0-9]:8080|awk -vabc=$ports_log_file 'BEGIN{"date +'%Y-%m-%d-%r'"|getline d;}/8080/{print d,$0 >> abc  }')
if [ "$cmd-out" -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "error port 8080: $cmd_out" >> $ports_not_listening    #expected the return status not 0 for failure
else
        echo "Print success for port-8080: $?" #expected the return status 0 for successful run
fi
## mail the ports that are not listening
if [ -e "${ports_not_listening}" ] ; then
    ## mailx the ports that are not listening, for now just echo to stdout
    echo "$ports_not_listening"
fi
exit 0;

output expected:
2015-01-12-05:38:00 PM tcp        0     0 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:*                 LISTEN 
2016-01-13-05:39:02 PM tcp        0      0 0.0.0.1:8080              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

could anyone verify the command and correct me how to quote. what would be right approach to achieve this.

Comment: Rather than stating an `X-Y` problem, state your requirement clearly with a proper input and expected output. I am sure there are better ways than this without needing `eval`

Comment: I am using this approach to capture the return status of the netstat command. After this command, need to check "$? -eq 0" for success or failure of the command executed.

Comment: You don't need `eval` for that. Any command ran on the shell has a return code stored in `$?`

Comment: Are you planning to let know the requirement? Else this is going to get closed as off-topic

Comment: if [[ ! -e $ports_log_dir ]]; then
    mkdir -p "$ports_log_dir"
fi
eval "netstat -na | grep [0-9]:80|awk -vabc=$ports_log_file 'BEGIN{"date"|getline d;}/80/{print d,\$0 >> abc  }'"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "error port 80" >> $ports_not_listening
else
        echo "success for port-80: $?"
fi
if [ -e "${ports_not_listening}" ] ; then
 echo "$ports_not_listening"
fi
exit 0;
Expected output:
2015-01-12-05:38:00 PM tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN

Comment: Requirement is like above.

Comment: @arunp: If you need to provide additional information about your question, do so by *editing the question*. Comments are not appropriate, particularly when they include lots of code.

Comment: @rici - I could not see the edit enabled so pasted in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not just

```
$  netstat -na | 
   awk -v d="$(date)" '/[0-9]:80/ {f=1; print d,$0} 
                       END        {exit f?0:1}' >> $ports_log_file; echo $?
```

if any line matches sets the flag f, and uses the complement as the exit status.

Comment: elegant solution. In my script, the script will succeed even though there is no ports running in the output. The f flag and END block with ?: operator does the trick. But in the regex it will match string ports 80 or other ports like 80**(8080). is there a way to search only specific ports(no extra digits).

Comment: for that you may want to add a space after 80.

Comment: there is a match command to find exact string. the command is 'match($0, /\y[0-9]:443\y/)' which search the pattern. it worked.

Comment: word delimiters would do as well.

Comment: Nice to know different ways.I will try the -F options as well.